# VB.Net does not throw compiler error when setting Dictionary to IList

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-errors

I am updating a legacy application, and it was reading a dll from another project for a Dictionary(of Guid, String) of items and using them.

The requirements have changed, and the method that was returning the Dictionary is now returning an IList.

This is the odd behavior of this; the intellisense is not throwing a cast error, nor is the compiler.  It does not throw an error until runtime when it tries to set the Dictionary to the IList.

Example:

```
        Dim someDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Dim someList As IList(Of Integer)
        someDictionary = someList
```

Any idea as to why the compiler is not catching this?

Comment: Because VB.Net does not check *type safety* - I've never considered VB to be a strongly typed language. VB allows a lot of implicit casting that C# will scream about long before you try to compile.

Comment: @IAbstract: With Option Explicit and Option Strict on, VB is pretty strongly typed...

Comment: @Jon: I guess I was Option Wrong  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives an error when "[Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)" is On:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim someDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = _
               New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Dim someList As IList(Of Integer) = Nothing
        someDictionary = someList
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error:

> error BC30512: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of Integer)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, String)'.
>
> ```
>    someDictionary = someList
> ```

I suggest you change your project to enable Option Strict, to help catch this sort of thing :)